# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'model' in undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

i'm learning Backbone.js from the online book 'backbone-fundamentals',
while trying the example i got an error in console related to underscore.js:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'model' in undefined
```

i searched for the error on SO what i found as the cause of this error was that i should not pass strings to my model when initializing it. but i didn't.

here is my project, my model:

```
// models/todo.js    
var app = app || {};

app.Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        title: '',
        completed: false
    },

    toggle: function() {
        this.save({
            completed: !this.get('completed')
        });
    }
});
```

my collection:

```
// collections/todos.js
var app = app || {};

var TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.Todo,

    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('todos-backbone'),

    completed: function() {
        return this.filter( function( todo ) {
            return todo.get('completed');
        });
    },

    remaining: function() {
        return this.without.apply(this, this.completed());
    },

    nextOrder: function() {
        if( !this.length ) {
            return 1;
        }
        return this.last().get('order') + 1;
    },

    comperator: function(todo) {
        return todo.get('order');
    }
});

app.Todos = new TodoList();
```

i have two views.

```
// views/todos.js
var app = app || {};


app.TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',

    template: _.template( $('#item-template').html() ),

    events: {
        'dbclick label': 'edit',
        'keypress .edit': 'updateOnEnter',
        'blur .edit': 'close'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.attributes) );
        this.$input = this.$('.edit');
        return this;
    },

    edit: function() {
        this.$el.addClass('editing');
        this.$input.focus();
    },

    close: function() {
        var value = this.$input.val().trim();

        if( value ) {
            this.model.save({ title: value });
        }

        this.$el.removeClass('editing');
    },

    updateOnEnter: function(e) {
        if (e.which === ENTER_KEY) {
            this.close();
        }
    }
});
```

and:

```
// views/app.js
// maybe i should rename this file to appView.js
var app = app || {};

app.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.todoapp',

    statsTemplate: _.template( $('#stats-template').html() ),

    events: {
        'keypress .new-todo': 'createOnEnter',
        'click .clear-completed': 'clearCompleted',
        'click .toggle-all': 'toggleAllComplete'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.allCheckbox = this.$('.toggle-all')[0];
        this.$input = this.$('.new-todo');
        this.$footer = this.$('.footer');
        this.$main = this.$('.main');

        this.listenTo(app.Todos, 'add', this.addOne);
        this.listenTo(app.Todos, 'reset', this.addAll);

        this.listenTo(app.Todos, 'change:completed', this.filterOne);
        this.listenTo(app.Todos, 'filter', this.filterAll);
        this.listenTo(app.Todos, 'all', this.render);

        app.Todos.fetch();
    },

    render: function() {
        var completed = app.Todos.completed().length;
        var remaining = app.Todos.remaining().length;

        if(app.Todos.length) {
            this.$main.show();
            this.$footer.show();

            this.$footer.html(this.statsTemplate({
                completed: completed,
                remaining: remaining
            }));

            this.$('#filters li a')
                .removeClass('selected')
                .filter('[href="#/' + (app.TodoFilter || '' ) + '"]')
                .addClass('selected');
        } else {
            this.$main.hide();
            this.$footer.hide();
        }

        this.allCheckbox.checked = !remaining;
    },

    addOne: function(todo) {
        var view = new app.TodoView({ model:todo });
        $('.todo-list').append( view.render().el );
    },

    addAll: function() {
        this.$('.todo-list').html('');
        app.Todos.each(this.addOne, this);
    },

    filterOne: function(todo) {
        todo.trigger('visible');
    },

    filterAll: function() {
        app.Todos.each(this.filterOne, this);
    },

    newAttributes: function() {
        return {
            title: this.$input.val().trim(),
            order: app.Todos.nextOrder(),
            completed: false
        };
    },

    createOnEnter: function( event ) {
        if( event.which !== ENTER_KEY || !this.$input.val().trim() ) {
            return;
        }

        app.Todos.create( this.newAttributes() );
        this.$input.val('');
    },

    clearCompleted: function() {
        _.invoke(app.Todos.completed(), 'destroy');
        return false;
    },

    toggleAllComplete: function() {
        var completed = this.allCheckbox.checked;

        app.Todos.each(function(todo) {
            todo.save({
                'completed': completed
            });
        });
    }

});
```

app.js :

```
// js/app.js

var app = app || {};
var ENTER_KEY = 13;
var ESC_KEY = 27;

    $(function() {

        new app.AppView();

    });
```

where should i look when such an error happens?
thank you for your time...

edit:
  the error happens when i load the page without doing anything further.
  the order of the files is:

```
<script src="js/models/todo.js"></script>
<script src="js/collections/todos.js"></script>
<script src="js/views/todos.js"></script>
<script src="js/views/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/routers/router.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

the whole error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'model' in undefined
   (anonymous function) @   underscore.js:5
   j.each.j.forEach @   underscore.js:5
   j.pick   @   underscore.js:5
   Backbone.View    @   backbone.js:1190
   child    @   backbone.js:1852
   (anonymous function) @   app.js:9
   n.Callbacks.j    @   jquery.js:2
   n.Callbacks.k.fireWith   @   jquery.js:2
   n.extend.ready   @   jquery.js:2
   K    @   jquery.js:2
```

Comment: You don't tell us when you get the error. Is it when you open the page or when you add a Todo or what?

Comment: just as i load the page i get the error...

Comment: In what order are you loading all of these files?

Comment: oops, sorry, i edited the post so now the order in the question is the same way that they are loaded. mention that `/views/todos.js` comes before `/views/app.js` . thanks again. i appreciate your time.

Comment: Well, I can't find any obvious mistakes. Can you give us the whole error message?

Comment: edited the post again.

Comment: i went to [here](http://backbonejs.org/examples/todos/index.html) and i copied everything except the libs and tried locally. i got the same error. so i copied the libs too and it's working now! seem to be a problem with version of libs i'm using. by the way, thank you...

Comment: OK, np, glad you figured it out :).